# How to do Task.ContinueWith<Task>(...)

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I use HttpClient and I want to write something like that:

```
HttpClient client = ...;
Task<string> getContent()
{
    return client.GetAsync(...)
   .ContinueWith( t => t.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() );
}
```

I know I can write

```
.ContinueWith( t => t.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

but one of pool's threads will be blocked. 
I want continueWithTask like in the [Google Task library](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#continueWithTask(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation%3CTResult,%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3CTContinuationResult%3E%3E)).

How can I accomplish it?

**UPDATE**

And yes, I do need to use Tasks instead of async/await and I really know what I want.

**UPDATE2**

I revised my views and now I think that I was wrong in choosing the technology. If anyone doubts, here is a [great example](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-conclusion.html) of good code.

Comment: important question: *why* do you want to use `ContinueWith`? the default these days should be to `await` it instead

Comment: It wont be blocked because `.Result` in `ContinueWith` will return already completed Task. Just use async/await

Comment: Why use that at all? No, you don't need to use tasks "instead of" async/await. These things work together. There's nothing that prevents you from writing `async Task<string> getContent() { var response=await client.GetAsync(); return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsyng();}`

Comment: You could also use `Task<string> getContent()=>client.GetStringAsync(someUrl);`

Comment: Why do you call `client.GetAsync()` inside `Task.Run`? this is an async call so it already returns a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`. It doesn't need to be wrapped in `Task.Run()`. Without that, the `ContinueWith()` would work. The result would be a `Task<Task<string>>` that would need an `Unwrap()` to get at the Task<string>

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ok,  I just made a mistake when I wrote an example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These days you should avoid `ContinueWith`, preferring `async`/`await` unless you have *very very specific reasons*; I suspect this will work:

```cs
async Task<string> getContent()
{
    var foo = await client.GetAsync(...); // possibly with .ConfigureAwait(false)
    return await foo.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // possibly with .ConfigureAwait(false)
}
```

Comment: It is not an answer to my question.

Comment: @AlexeySubbota it is the proper answer. You have to explain why you don't want to use it. The way the question is now, it's not possible to give any other answer

Comment: @AlexeySubbota to explain with a colourful metaphor: if someone is saying "my shotgun keeps jamming when I point it straight down at my foot; how do I fix that?", the most correct answer is not to show them how to unjam it when held vertically - it is to advise them to shoot away from their feet. It is also perhaps reasonable to ask "why are you trying to shoot your foot off?", just in case there is an unlikely but genuine reason for it. So: if you have a *reason* to aim at your feet, I'm all ears. Until then: please point the shotgun away from body parts.

Comment: @MarcGravell There are some reasons for not using async. One of them is possibility of cancellation. what would you say about that?

Comment: @MarcGravell The second reason. Imagine a long sequence of calls and only last one starts asynchronous operation. And the caller doesn't need to wait completion. I don't want to mark all functions in the chain as async, because all code will be marked async then. Instead, I can mark only last function and return void but documentation says return void only from event handlers. And I am afraid something bad might happen.

Comment: @MarcGravell How can I specify TaskScheduler for awaiting? Once I having use ConfigurateAwait(false) I cannot return to main thread then. The comments don't have enough space for an example.

Comment: @AlexeySubbota: 1) `async` works fine with cancellation via `CancellationToken`. 2) *Asynchronous* code grows through the codebase, not just `async`; this is true whether you use `async` or `Task` or callbacks - and it's easier to propagate `async` than any other pattern. 3) If you need to return to the calling context, then don't use `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: @AlexeySubbota first reason: pass a `CancellationToken` in (and check it appropriately): done; 2) that's fine - but the moment you're using `ContinueWith`, you've switched over and might as well have used `await`; if you want to write optimized fast path for bits that are synchronous, that's fine too - I *routinely* do that, and there are well-known mechanisms to get the best of both without needing either `await` or `ContinueWith` when it isn't actually async yet (but still be task-like); 3) as @StephenCleary - only the bits that don't need context should use `ConfigureAwait(false)`

Answer (score 3):

> And yes, I do need to use Tasks instead of async/await and I really know what I want.

I strongly recommend [Marc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54588515/263693). I cannot think of a good reason not to use `async`/`await` unless you are stuck on .NET 4.0 (i.e., Windows XP). And that can't be the case because you're using `HttpClient` and `Task.Run`. So please bear in mind that this answer is *purely instructional* and *not recommended for production*.

`ContinueWith` calls can be "chained", kind-of similar to how `Promise.then` works in JavaScript, but the out-of-the-box C# chaining semantics are more awkward than JavaScript's.

For one thing, `Task<Task<T>>` types are not automatically unwrapped. There is an `Unwrap` method available. For another, the use of `.Result` - a TPL relic more naturally used with `ContinueWith` - will wrap exceptions in an `AggregateException`, which can cause an interesting kind of "cascade" where your inner exception can get buried deeply inside nested `AggregateException` instances. Hence the presence of `AggregateException.Flatten` to straighten out the mess after-the-fact. Oh, and you should [***always*** pass a `TaskScheduler` to `ContinueWith`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html).

Here's a first attempt, explicitly specifying the `TaskScheduler`, using `Unwrap` to unwrap nested tasks, and avoiding the nested exceptions by using `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of `Result`:

```
Task<string> getContent()
{
  // I am so sorry, future coder, but I cannot use await here because <insert good reason>
  return Task.Run(()=> client.GetAsync(...))
      .ContinueWith(t => t.GetAwaiter().GetResult().Content.ReadAsStringAsync(), TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap()
      .ContinueWith(t => t.GetAwaiter().GetResult(), TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

If you do this a lot in your code, you may want to use [something like `.Then`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/11/21/processing-sequences-of-asynchronous-operations-with-tasks/) that encapsulates some of this logic. Oh, and be sure to write an apology in the comments; even if the future maintainer is yourself, that's just the polite thing to do with code like this. ;)

Comment: That moment when I want to downvote my own answer. Well, I suppose I'll have to be content with upvoting [Marc's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54588515/263693)...

Comment: all is not lost, maybe you will convince me)

Comment: @AlexeySubbota: The code in Marc's answer is shorter, easier to read, and easier to maintain (no real pitfalls like "you have to pass a `TaskScheduler`" and "use this long `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` thing to avoid awkward error handling"). Why *not* use that answer?

Comment: I wrote several reasons why I _did_ not want this, in the comments to Marс’s answer. Now I understand that I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> but one of pool's threads will be blocked

That's not the case because the `ContinueWith` delegate is only called once the "antecedent" task has completed. `Result` will not block and it's even synchronization free.

The second `.Result` (`ReadAsStringAsync().Result`) is blocking, though. So you have to turn that into another `ContinueWith`.

In general, a sequence of sequential IOs turns into a sequence of `ContinueWith`.

In general, `await` is preferable here but you indicated that this would not work for you.